# Requests to Social Tables are showing a 401 unauthorized error

Tags: social-tables

Our software has had an integration with Social Tables for some time, but recently most requests seem to be returning a 401 Unauthorized error. I have confirmed that the access token we are sending is valid. We are using the layout-automation calls.

One of my most recent requests had the body

```html
{
    "category": "Bowling",
    "end_time": "2021-05-16T09:00:00.000Z",
    "name": "Bowling: Test Event",
    "start_time": "2021-05-16T08:00:00.000Z",
    "spaces": [
        {
            "name": "Buyout",
            "venue_id": "S133191",
            "wizard": {
                "attendees": 50,
                "setup": "aligned",
                "spacing": {
                    "x": 24,
                    "y": 30
                },
                "table": {
                    "chairs": 6,
                    "size": {
                        "length": 36,
                        "width": 48
                    },
                    "type": "rectangle",
                    "cullAdditionalTables": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Prior to this request the access token was renewed successfully and that the access token we provided was the newly updated access token. Any assistance with this error would be appreciated. If there is more information that we can provide, let me know.

---

Answer (score 0):

Do calls to apis other than layout-automation work properly?

Comment: We only use the layout-automation call and the call to refresh the tokens. We have a very basic integration to Social Tables, only enough to create the layout in Social Tables.

Comment: What is likely happening is that team/company you are trying to perform the layout-automation action on does not have the layout automation module.

If you send me the first part of your email address (leave off the domain) we can look you up in the system and email you directly.

Comment: Perfect! The first part of the email I am testing with is: unleashedadmin. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Coming back to this, I hadn't seen a follow up to this and realized that the email that account was tied to was no longer available. I setup a new account starting with adam.jaffray.